# Webots - Avoid (part of) robot sinking into RectangleArena; and how to affix it to the ground

Tags: robotics, webots

I've this robot with physics and all:

[image]

The problem I face is that, as soon as I start the simulation, a part of the robot will sink into the RectangleArena, like this:

[image]

The Robot does have some weird joints, but if you pay attention to the bottom cylinder, it's like 10% into the Arena. I'm not sure why this is happening, any pointers shall be appreciated. I'm happy to provide more code if needed. Additionally, I wonder how I can fix the bottom cylinder to the ground so it becomes immovable, i.e. only upper part of the hand should move with joints. I've tried giving it big enough mass, but that doesn't seem to be working well, and I think there has to be a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should simply remove the `Physics` node of the base of the robot (bottom cylinder) to attach it to the static world. See https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/physics#how-to-use-physics-nodes for a full explanation.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. I wonder if you could also comment on the cylinder sinking into the arena part. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Attaching the cylinder to the static world should also fix it so that it doesn't sink into the floor any more.